# extracting facebook second degree friends IOS objective-c

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to extract the profile of my friends, friends.
me --> Andy --> Dona

I'm friends with Andy so I can get his data as well as see that Dona is his friend but how do I get all the information (name, gender, location etc) of dona when all I have it's her FB userID?

I've tried calling the following, replacing @"me" with dona `id` as well as `profile/<id>` but both failed

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                       parameters:@{ @"fields": @"name,picture,email,friendlists",}]//picture.type(large)
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
 }];
```

Comment: You can not replace "me" what do you want. There are some specific parameters. Read Facebook Graph API documentation [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph)

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam do you have an idea how can I achieve what I'm looking for (BTW: I read  Graph API several time - I'm asking here because I didn't find what I need)

Comment: You don’t get information such as the email address or their friendlists, unless that user logs in to your app and grants it permission.

Comment: @CBroe yes I know that, what I can't figure out is what to send to init graph instead of @"me" that will be my friend's id

Comment: That should be just `initWithGraphPath:@"1234"`